# Resizing an array using pointers not working properly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a dynamic array to store objects of class "Song". As user adds/deletes more songs to the playlist the dynamic array should resize itself accordingly. The "add_song()" function should resize the songs array and then add the new song at the end of it.

I've thought of using a temp array and first copying everything to temp and then after resizing i add everything back to songs...

```
class Song{
  private:
    string name;
    int size = 0;
    Song* songs ;
    .....accessors and mutators.
};
class Playlist{
  public:
    void add_song()
        {
            if(size == 0)
            {
                songs= new Song[1];
                songs[0].set_info();
                size++;
            }
            else
            {
                size++;
                Song* temp = new Song[size];
                for(int x=0;x<size-1;x++)
                {
                    temp[x] = songs[x];
                }
                temp[size].set_info();
                delete [] songs;
                songs = new Song[size];
                for(int x = 0; x<size; x++)
                {   
                    songs[x] = temp[x];
                }
                delete [] temp;             
            }
            
        }
};
```

I cant seem to understand what's wrong with this code.... The output is fine when i add the first song in the playlist object ... after that it doesnt add songs to the playlist obj

Comment: What "set_info()" does is just set values for the member variable of the Song class

Comment: have you heard of `std::vector` or `std::list`?

Comment: @billz i have but im not **allowed** to use them

Comment: `temp[size].set_info();` -- This is a memory overwrite.  Ask yourself what is the value of `size`, and what the valid index values you can use in an array of `size` elements.  Also, why do you have two `songs = new Song[size];` in the function?

Comment: You also do not need a special case for `size == 0`.  All you need is to add one to size and write the correct resizing code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie lets say "songs" has 4 elements. what im doing is making temp with 5 indexes and in the last index ie temp[4] i add the thing that needed space in the first place...then i copy temp into songs and delete temp

Comment: `Song* temp = new Song[size];` -- `temp[size].set_info();` -- So you don't see an issue with this?  The valid indices are 0 up to `size-1`.  Also, your explanation of why you are creating two sets of arrays doesn't really make a lot of sense.  All you need to do is 1) Create a new, larger empty array.  2) Copy the old array to the new array.  3) Delete the old array.  4) Set `songs` equal to the new array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've already taken into account that size-1 thing in code not shown here.....that is not the problem. the problem is that when using the "add_songs()" function for the 2nd time the console just stops at " temp[size].set_info() " then exits

Comment: I am looking at the code you posted.  You allocated `size` elements, and then attempting to call a function on `temp[size]` -- that is totally wrong.  It is a memory overwrite or at least a memory access violation, as the valid indices go up to `size-1`.  Your code exhibits undefined behavior as a result of this.  Also, it doesn't matter what the loop you had is doing -- that's not the issue.  The issue is what you did *after* the loop.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i get what u mean now....will update soon thanks a bunch

Comment: Wasn't this already asked yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your `add_song` function:

1. It access an out-of-bounds item of the dynamically allocated array.
2. It unnecessarily calls `new[]` twice.
3. There is no need to have special code for `size == 0`.

Here is a rewrite of the function:

```
  void add_song()
  {
      // allocate size + 1 songs 
      Song* temp = new Song[size + 1];

      // copy songs over to the new array
      for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
          temp[x] = songs[x];

      // set the information for the last song added
      temp[size].set_info();

      // adjust the size to the new amount
      ++size;

     // delete the old array and set songs to the new array
      delete [] songs;
      songs = temp;
   }
```

Note how the `size` is incremented *after* the allocation of `size + 1` elements and the setting of the last element in `temp` using `set_info`.  Your issue is that you incremented `size` at the very beginning, causing this:

`temp[size].set_info();`

to access an invalid index.

Comment: This is exactly what i did just right now (i mean remove the" size++ " from the start and its working alright now thanks again!!!

Comment: Good advice would be to use `std::vector` instead of manual memory manipulation.